# Why am I receiving this error when attempting to unmount external CF card?

Tags: macos, terminal, external-disk, mount

Sometimes I receive the following error when trying to unmount an external USB, CF, or random drive:

`dissented by PID 17728 (/usr/bin/login)`

I attempted to `cd` out of the drive directory, and into my home directory, then unmount, but that didn't change it. I've tried opening new Terminal sessions and trying but still receive the error.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: which command are you using to unmount?

Comment: @KevinGrabher `diskutil unmount`